# Shopify 429 request issue using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, horizon

I using laravel horizon for creating products using api.

but I facing issue of 429 too many request.

below is my horizon setup

```
'environments' => [
        'production' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'minProcesses' => 1,
                'maxProcesses' => 4,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
        ],

        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['default'],
                'balance' => 'auto',
                'minProcesses' => 1,
                'maxProcesses' => 4,
                'tries' => 1,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Increase the number of request limit

Comment: it's already too much but question how to manage when I get 429 error from Shopify, it has bucket limit of 40 at time

Comment: We have two solution
1) Increase the number of request limit from shopify
2) Manage request from laravel or decrease laravel request

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution.

I made one cron who will track the total count in Shopify pending basket.

if cron found countless then 30 then it will more 100 requests.

every minute cron will check this.